# C# HTTPListener: refuse TLS version lower than 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ssl, tls1.2

I have a server application on Windows (Server) who's code is originally created using `.net35` but I build it on `.net46` (can't change this due to legacy reasons).

I want HttpListener to refuse a handshake with a client if the TLS version is lower than 1.2. (checking `context.Request.GetClientCertificate().Version` after the handshake kind of works but is not a desirable solution)

I've tried using exe.config in combination with setting the tls version of `ServicepointManger.SecurityProtocol` (tls 1.2 is not in .net35 hence that I define it myself) before creating the HttpListener

```
        SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
        SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
        m_server = new HttpListener();
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.ServiceModel.DisableUsingServicePointManagerSecurityProtocols=false"/>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=true"/>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=true"/>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.ServiceModel.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Multiple sources mention that I could configure the registry but I would prefer to avoid that to prevent potentially breaking other (legacy) applications.

Comment: Ideally you would just reconfigure the registry, but you say you don't want that. "checking context.Request.GetClientCertificate().Version kind of works but is not a desirable solution" why?

Comment: Because by then the handshake has already been made. 
I want that the handshake itself gets refused.

Comment: During testing I've noticed that the appliction would throw errors due to that line  and if the client used 1.0 or 1.1 the browser would show an error page (even with try catch). Which is handy if I want 1.2 but not if I want 1.1.

Comment: There are known issue with TLS encryption with Net libraries before 4.7.2.  TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 where disabled years ago by a Windows Security update that disables these versions.  TLS uses certificates which contains different encryption modes.  You have to use a TLS version that is compatible with the certificate you are using.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.  Enabling TLS 1.2 is setting a static bit in a Windows register to turn TLS on.  But Net  version before 4.7.2 does the TLS while later version uses the OS.  I recommend using Net 4.7.2.

Comment: SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00; is setting the TLS mode requested by client.  It does not change the listener.

Comment: @jdweng The version of TLS has almost nothing to do with the certificate used (except that some algorithms are not supported on older versions). It is technically possible to create a TLS connection without using a certificate at all.

Comment: @Charlieface : How can you make a secure connection without a crypto key?

Comment: @jdweng DH_anon and ECDH_anon cipher suites don't use certificates, they're anonymous. Obviously they are subject to MITM attacks and therefore disabled in almost all implementations. Essentially the TLS spec only defines how to set up a secure conenction, it doesn't by itself specify the cipher suite (eg AES) or how that cipher is secured (eg certificates). Theoretically you could use Kerberos to set up a perfectly secure TLS connection without certificates, but I've never seen that (Kerberos is normally used with a completely separate secure connection type called Negotiate)

Comment: @Charlieface : What you said is wrong.  TLS there is always a key loaded in both client and server.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng Not with EC/DH_anon. There is no permanent asymmetric key (like an RSA or EC certificate), only an ephemeral key. It's rarely used though, but my point is that TLS is separate from the cipher used, it's just a protocol to negotiate a secure tunnel using any agreed cipher and parameters. TLS <> AES <> RSA <> certificates, TLS has protocol versions which support various things, there are negotiation methods within that, normally via supported ciphers using keys and other parameters in certificates.